# What are the values returned by tkinter.Button.configure()

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I don't understand the output of "button.configure("text")". This function returns a tuple. what are the elements of the tuple?

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
root = Tk()


button = ttk.Button(root, text=("Hello"))
button.grid()

print(button.configure("text"))

root.mainloop()
```

output is:

```
('text', 'text', 'Text', '', 'Hello')
```

Comment: If you want to retrieve the text of your button directly, you can use `button["text"]`.

Answer (score 1):

From the [`Tcl.tk` docs](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.4/TkLib/ConfigWidg.htm#M36):

> ...Otherwise the list will contain five values: argvName,
>   dbName, dbClass, defValue, and current value. The current value is
>   computed from the appropriate field of widgRec by calling procedures
>   like Tk_NameOfColor.

It means that `tkinter` returns a tuple extracted from a list of five values, which are, in sequence:

> argvName, dbName, dbClass, defValue, and current value

in your case:

```
('text', 'text', 'Text', '', 'Hello')

argvName = 'text'  
dbName = 'text'
dbClass = 'Text'
defValue = ''
current value = 'Hello'
```